# when I click the anchor tag I need to be navigated to a different page & in that page I need a modal to be shown Using Javascript

Tags: javascript

when I click the anchor tag I need to be navigated to a different page & in that page I need a modal to be shown.How Can I do that I have tried in so many ways but Noting could Help me... Can anyone help me in this Thank you...

Here is my Code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Shiva</h1>
    
    <a href="/something/121212"></a>
    
    <script>
        fetch('http://localhost:3000/data').then(res =>{
             return res.json()
        }).then(data =>{
            data.map(dating =>{
               const markup = ` <li>${dating.name}</li> `
               document.querySelector('a').insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', markup)
            })
        })

        
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you explain what exactly are to trying to achieve with the above code. Is your requirement simply to show a modal when a anchor tag is clicked instead of navigation? Or do you have a broader need?

Comment: @JibinBose , Thank you for your response..... I need Navigation with the Modal Popup When I clicked on the anchor tag, Can you please help in that ??

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong, when you click the anchor tag you need to be navigated to a different page & in that page you need a modal to be shown?

Comment: @JibinBose Yes yes Exactly I need that

Comment: In that case, you need that logic in your destination pages onload function.

Comment: @JibinBose, Ok Can you please Edit my Code and show me where I need to do changes... I am new to JavaScript

Comment: @sandi I have given example code in the answer. Try that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the answer for your use case.

Let's say the code you have a home page with an anchor tag that points to profile page. Your need is to show a modal as soon as the profile page loads up.

Let's assume you navigate to profile.html from your current page using anchor tag. Then your profile.html will look something like this.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
  <title>Profile</title>
  <link
    rel="stylesheet"
    href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.0.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
    integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm"
    crossorigin="anonymous"
  />
</head>
<body>
  <!-- Modal -->
  <div
    class="modal fade"
    id="exampleModal"
    tabindex="-1"
    role="dialog"
    aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel"
    aria-hidden="true"
  >
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
          <button
            type="button"
            class="close"
            data-dismiss="modal"
            aria-label="Close"
          >
            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
          </button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">...</div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">
            Close
          </button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- Modal -->

  <script
    src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"
    integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN"
    crossorigin="anonymous"
  ></script>
  <script
    src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.12.9/dist/umd/popper.min.js"
    integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q"
    crossorigin="anonymous"
  ></script>
  <script
    src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.0.0/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
    integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl"
    crossorigin="anonymous"
  ></script>
  <script>
    window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
      $("#exampleModal").modal("show");
    });
  </script>
</body>
```

The main catch here is the eventListener that checks if the DOM has loaded & then fires a javascript event to show the modal.

```
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
  $("#exampleModal").modal("show");
});
```

Please refer to this snippet for a reference using jQuery & Bootstrap modal. Rework on the same as per your need.

Answer (score 0):

I think first remove the href on anchor tag. Then use onClick on anchor tag.Because href will directly redirect to the provided url

Comment: But I need to Redirect to another url when i click on that anchor tag with model popup

Comment: Simply removing the href wont be of no use. The ideal approach will be prevent the default behaviour of the anchor tag using javascript & show the modal.

If you actually don't need a navigation to happen, ideally you should not use the anchor tag & rely on a button tag that does same onClick handler.

Answer (score 0):

See this example below:

---

Add an identifier on your query param like `openModal=true` so that you can track the page you want to open the modal. I guess you don't need to open the modal everytime you visit the page.

```html
<a href="/something/121212?openModal=true">Click here</a>
```

---

Now, on the page you redirected after clicking the link, when the page is fully loaded, get the query param

```js
<script>
  window.onload = (event) => {
  const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
  const shouldOpenModal = urlParams.get("openModal");

  if (shouldOpenModal == "true") {
    // open your modal
  }
};
</script>
```

---

If I summarize the solution, on the page you want to show the modal, wait for the page to load fully. Then show the modal.

The `openModal=true` query param is just to track if you want to open the modal by clicking on that specific link you created by anchor tag, not when you visit the page in some other way or other links. You can avoid the query param and condition check if you always want to show the modal every time visiting the page.

Comment: nvm, just saw your comments, seems you want to redirect to a new page and then open the modal @sandi

Comment: Yes exactly, Can you help me in that

Comment: this is strange why my comment never showed up here, I updated my solution and commented here to let you know. seems like you got the solution :D weird that my comment was gone. @sandi

Answer (score 0):

You can use boostrap modal and trigger it through Javascript. Here is an example code:-

```js
var myModal = new bootstrap.Modal(document.getElementById('exampleModalToggle'));
    myModal.show();
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-KK94CHFLLe+nY2dmCWGMq91rCGa5gtU4mk92HdvYe+M/SXH301p5ILy+dN9+nJOZ" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ENjdO4Dr2bkBIFxQpeoTz1HIcje39Wm4jDKdf19U8gI4ddQ3GYNS7NTKfAdVQSZe" crossorigin="anonymous"></script> 

 <!-- Modal Trigger through Button -->

<a class="btn btn-primary" data-bs-toggle="modal" href="#exampleModalToggle" role="button">Open first modal</a>

  <!-- Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModalToggle" aria-hidden="true" aria-labelledby="exampleModalToggleLabel" tabindex="-1">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalToggleLabel">Modal 1</h5>
          <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          Show a second modal and hide this one with the button below.
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button class="btn btn-primary" data-bs-target="#exampleModalToggle2" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Open second modal</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

I am triggering the modal on page load. You can adjust as you want. Hope it will be helpful.